# I need to make a structure for a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a table that saves users:
Email || Username || age || password
and I need to save the series they have seen and the ones they are watching and as I have read it is not correct to insert two columns with vectors that save the series, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Build another table with 3 columns

- the primary key of `users` (perhaps `email`?).
- what they are watching,
- when.

Each user would have any number (0 or more) rows in this table.

Think this way:  When you need a "vector", make a new table.